Can I save which windows are on which desktops / spaces?
I use "spaces" to organize my windows.  For example, I might have 6 different VS Code projects open at the same time as separate windows, and it's easiest to switch between them if I have a physical location to jump to, rather than cycling through until I find the one I want.  But VS Code requires a restart daily to stay up to date, at which point all those windows reopen crammed together on the same space, meaning that I have to manually redistribute them to the spaces I want them on.  Is there any setting or mechanism at all, even if it's an app I have to buy, that will allow me to avoid or otherwise automate this?

I’m traveling so I can’t test this, but take a look at Bunch: https://bunchapp.co/docs/ . You can switch spaces and have files open in a specific app. You’ll need to experiment with delays between opening and switching to the next space.
